# Why do Room Tables have duplicate id columns?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, stetho

I am investigating the use of `Room` in my current Android project.

When using `com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1` to check my Sqlite Tables structure and content I have discovered all my tables display with two identical columns of their primary key.

Is this a `stetho` "feature"?

or have I declared my Room entities incorrectly somehow?

All my `Kotlin` data model classes follow this pattern:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_table")
data class myDO(@ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
                          @ColumnInfo(name = "uuid") val uuid: String,
                          @ColumnInfo(name = "something") val something: String,
                          @ColumnInfo(name = "what_ever") val whatEver: String?,
                          @ColumnInfo(name = "misc_data") val miscData: String,
                          @ColumnInfo(name = "liked") val liked: Boolean) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var myId: Long = 0
}
```

Stetho displays this table as follows:-

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Column|Name|**myId**|**myId**|title|uuid|something|what_ever |misc_data|liked|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Comment: You can't have two columns with the same name on the same table in SQL. My guess is that this is a Stetho issue. Try copying the database to your development machine (e.g., use Device File Explorer in Android Studio) and examine it using a desktop SQLite client.

Comment: I was having the same issue. Both removing autoGenerate and setting it to false as mentioned below did nothing.  I still had a duplicate id field.  When I copied the database from the Device File Explorer and viewed it locally, there was only one id field.  It must be a Stetho issue.

Answer (score -5):

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

Since you have given *autoGenerate = true* 
it will create myId twice and have same value

remove it and try